# Python function that reads the file and write lines in tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have to make function draw(file_name),that read file with numbers:

```
100 50
150 100
50 100
100 150
```

something like this.one line is one coordinate x,y

And draw line in tkiner: 1st line=1st point to 2nd line=2nd point,2nd line=2nd point to 3 line=3point
[image]

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
def draw(file):
    file=open(file,"r")
    line=file.readline()
    i=line.find(" ")
    x, y = int(line[:i]), int(line[i:])
    while line != "":
        line = file.readline()
        i = line.find(" ")
        x2, y2 = int(line[:i]), int(line[i:])
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x2, y2)
        x,y=x2,y2            
    file.close()

draw("file.txt")
canvas.mainloop()
```

this is my code but it doesn't work

Comment: "why isn't my code working?" is off topic for this site. You need to be a bit more specific. Why do you think it's not working? Does it crash? Does it draw the wrong thing? What _specifically_ is the problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley I don’t know where the eror,i needed define one variable before starting cycle and cycle will define that same variable.

Comment: You must know _something_ about what is happening. Is it drawing the wrong picture? The right picture in the wrong color? The right picture in the wrong location? No picture at all?

Comment: @BryanOakley it write distance is too near for the line where is typed: canvas.create_line(x, y, x2, y2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

def draw(filename):
    points = []
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.split()
            x, y = (int(line[0]), int(line[1]))
            points.append((x,y))

    for i in range(0,len(points)-1):
        canvas.create_line(points[i][0], points[i][1], points[i+1][0],points[i+1][1])

draw("points.txt")
canvas.mainloop()
```

You need to use `canvas.create_line()` because it is lines that you want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?
I'm using line.split(' ') in order to get the x and y coords from the file

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

def draw(file):
    x = None
    y = None
    with open(file,"r") as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
            if x is None:
                x, y = line.strip().split(' ')
            else:
                x2, y2 = line.strip().split(' ')
                canvas.create_line(x, y, x2, y2)
                x = x2
                y = y2         

draw("file.txt")
canvas.mainloop()
```

If this doesn't work, can you explain why and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score -1):

`def draw(file):
    with open(file,"r") as f:
    x, y = int(line[:i]), int(line[i:])

        for line in f:
            i = line.find(" ")
            x2, y2 = int(line[:i]), int(line[i:])
            canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x2, y2)
            x,y=x2,y2

        file.close()`

Comment: An answer this is code only isn't very useful. We are forced to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character. Your answer would be much better if you included a short explanation about what you did.

Comment: code explains itself. Read it or debug it if you cant understand